# How to exclude a widget from page 1 of a paginated post

Tags: plugins, php, pages, widgets

I want certain widgets to not appear on page 1 of a paginated post, but appear on all other pages (page 2, 3 .. so on), and some other widgets to appear on only appear on page 1 and not the rest of the paginated pages.

I installed a plugin that lets you execute php in widgets, and then tried the following conditions in my widget:

1. This didn't work:

   ```
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   if(1 != $paged)
   ```
2. This didn't work either:

   ```
   if(!is_paged())
   ```
3. This didn't too:

   ```
   if($page>1)
   ```

I then installed the plugin "widget logic" and tried the condition `is_paged()` but that didn't work either.

That function is not global certainly.

Can anyone suggest how should I go about it?

Comment: [The codex page for `is_paged`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) explains why it doesn't work in your case. `page` is the query var on paginated posts, `paged` is the query var on archive pages.

Comment: @Milo, I see, but I tried `if(is_page())`  condition and that didn't work either.

Comment: the `page` query var was in reference to your first code snippet. `is_page` is for detecting the page post type.

Comment: @Milo Thanks! That worked like a charm. `$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
if(1 != $paged)` Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per the last comment, this is the correct answer:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'page', 1 );
if(1 != $paged) ...
```